# Install docs for python to libdir location

Tags: python, autotools, configure, automake

I have a project in which we have some documentation that is generated in Visual Studio which is parsed by the runtime of Python so that our users can do things like `help (our.module)` in the REPL window and get meaningful data.  We are switching to autotools for our build environment in Linux.  I must find a means of ensuring that the 2 xml files necessary are installed to `$(libdir)` by make.

My first attempt was to do something like this in Makefile.am

```
dist_lib_DATA = file1.xml file2.xml
```

However, this produced this result:

```
[afalanga@afalanga4 BuildSystemWork]$ autoreconf
Makefile.am:5: error: 'libdir' is not a legitimate directory for 'DATA'
autoreconf: automake failed with exit status: 1
```

It was told to me that there is a workaround mentioned *somewhere* in the autotools manuals.  I'm not finding it as yet.  The only method I can think of at this time for a "workaround" is to write a special rule in my Makefile.am which would copy the files.  Something like this

```
install_docs : file1.xml file2.xml
        cp $^ $(libdir)
```

Does this look correct or is there a better method of doing this?  Another method might be if python has other places where it looks for documentation, I might be able to install there?  Is this possible?  I'm not that familiar with the internals of python for "in-line" help.

Comment: `$(libdir)` will expand to `/usr/local/lib` - are you sure you want to put your XML files directly there? shouldn't that be more `$(pkglibdir)` or similar?

Comment: @umläute you're correct.  I was mistaken with this one.  I finally found the workaround in the GNU docs (someone on the autotools mailing list pointed it out).  I actually needed to push these into $(pyexecdir).  I think I have to wait a day before I can answer my own question though.